# Images move according to mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, user-experience

Does this type of design have a name?

https://playoverwatch.com

On the header, if you move your mouse cursor, the images move different distances to create depth

Also, is there an easy way like a prewritten script to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for [Parallax](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/).

The effect shown on the github page is on scroll... But can be linked to mouse move too.

Comment: Right, thanks. I found what I was looking for under parallax interactive background :)